# Comparing & updating list values inside of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

```
dict1 = {
    "domain1": ["53/tcp,open,domain", "80/tcp,open,http"],
    "domain2": ["22/tcp,open,ssh", "25/tcp,open,smtp", "80/tcp,open,http",
                "443/tcp,open,https"],
    "domain3":["22/tcp,open,ssh"]}
```

I want to compare **`dict2`** with **`dict1`** and check if there are new keys or values (which is list of open ports),If yes then update the `dict1`

```
dict2 = {
    "domain3":["22/tcp,open,ssh","443/tcp,open,https"],
    "domain4":["80/tcp,open,http", "443/tcp,open,https"],
    "domain5":["80/tcp,open,http", "443/tcp,open,https"]}
```

I did first part of the task i.e to find any new keys by comparing `dict2` with `dict1` **keys** & checking if there are any new keys in `dict2` & updating `dict1`.

```
new_item = {}
for i in dict2.keys():
    if i not in dict1.keys():
        new_item[i] = dict2[i]
        dict1[i] = dict2[i]
print("NEW DOMAINS FOUND : ",new_item)
print(dict1) ## UPDATED with New Domains Found
```

Here's the output:

```
NEW DOMAINS FOUND :  {
  'domain4': ['80/tcp,open,http', '443/tcp,open,https'],
  'domain5': ['80/tcp,open,http', '443/tcp,open,https']}
 {'domain1': ['53/tcp,open,domain', '80/tcp,open,http'],
  'domain2': ['22/tcp,open,ssh', '25/tcp,open,smtp', '80/tcp,open,http',
              '443/tcp,open,https'],
  'domain3': ['22/tcp,open,ssh'],
  'domain4': ['80/tcp,open,http', '443/tcp,open,https'],
  'domain5': ['80/tcp,open,http', '443/tcp,open,https']}
```

I need help solving second part of the task which is compare the values of dict2 with dict1, and if there are any new values in `dict2` then **update the dict1 with those values.**

If you look at `dict2[domain3]` and `dict1[domain3]`, there is an new value in `dict2[domain3]`, with this, now `dict1[domain3]` should get updated with those new value.

Output which I want on comparing `dict2` with `dict1` & updating values/keys:

**`dict1`**

```
{'domain1': ['53/tcp,open,domain', '80/tcp,open,http'],
 'domain2': ['22/tcp,open,ssh', '25/tcp,open,smtp', '80/tcp,open,http',
             '443/tcp,open,https'],
 'domain3': ["22/tcp,open,ssh", "443/tcp,open,https"],
 'domain4': ['80/tcp,open,http', '443/tcp,open,https'],
 'domain5': ['80/tcp,open,http', '443/tcp,open,https']}
```

If you need more information or have doubts, please leave the comment, and I will update the question.

Comment: Lesson Learnt : Always make replica of problem in much simplicity before posting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ordering of the elements inside the lists is not important, you can use the following:

```
dict3 = {}
for k, v in dict2.items():
    dict3[k] = list(set(dict1.get(k, []) + v))
```

Resulting `dict3`:

```
{'domain3': ['443/tcp,open,https', '22/tcp,open,ssh'], 
 'domain5': ['80/tcp,open,http', '443/tcp,open,https'], 
 'domain4': ['80/tcp,open,http', '443/tcp,open,https']}
```